# Google App Engine, content security policy issues

Tags: express, google-app-engine, http-headers, google-cloud-platform, content-security-policy

I am quite close to giving up on moving to app engine.

Currently I am unable to access any of the static files from my server, due to some `content-security-policy` headers being set by app engine, which I do not experience when running on local or compute engine.

I am simply trying to access my static folders.

**Error**:

```
The Content Security Policy directive 'default-src' contains 'frame-ancestors' as a source expression. Did you mean 'default-src ...; frame-ancestors...' (note the semicolon)?
```

**Response Headers**:

```
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
content-encoding: gzip
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' frame-ancestors 'self' https://console.cloud.google.com https://*.corp.google.com:* http://*.corp.google.com:*
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 26 Jun 2018 09:53:17 GMT
server: nginx/1.10.3
status: 404
vary: Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 google
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-powered-by: Express
```

I can see that there is an issue with CSP, but I am unsure on what I need to do to affect this...

I am using the flexible environment, with Express and Nodejs and the app is being hosted @ `https://my-project-dot-blha.appspot.com`

**UPDATE**:
Whilst I can see that most likely it is a syntax error, I am trying to set the header myself in express and am unable to, if anyone knows how to affect these app-engine headers that would be ace!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using Express for serving your static content? Surely this could be served using Nginx?

Comment: @ScottMcC do you mean using the app.yaml file and specifying handlers there? But whichever way, they do support this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files#example_of_serving_static_files_with_your_app

Comment: Also Scott would this remove this issue? Or are you saying I run Nginx on a separate compute instance?

Comment: Have you specified static_files in your app.yml?

Comment: I am not using app.yaml to serve the files - express is doing this. Also is app.yaml even used until you deploy the app?

Comment: Could you share a snippet code of how you are implementing Express?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**!

When using app engine web preview, there are Content Security Policies set by GAE server to I guess ensure you do not share or use those preview domains. They allow access from users opening it from console environment.

If you want to bypass it you can use: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en

Otherwise when I deployed the app to what is the prod environment, this issue did not exist!